# "USB is also a serial communication method" is this true?

Tags: usb, serial, communication

I'll repeat the title. Is it true that USB is also a serial communication method ? (a bit confused, someone told me @ facebook :D)

Comment: How did this question get 2 upvotes? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus

Comment: Yes. Most modern communication channels are (FireWire, SATA).

Comment: This question needs to be more specific, what are you confused about in particular?

Comment: @NickHalden  ... and where's Olin when he's needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most wired communication nowadyas is serial, and so is USB. Serial just means that bits are transferred one after another in time, so that you only need one wire (two if you want to do it differential, like in USB). Expensive term: *Time Division Multiplex*, compared to *Space Division Multiplex*, where different bits use different physical wires in parallel. Remember the old IDE hard disks, floppy drives and SCSI devices for instance and the flat cables they used.

[image]

Serial has the advantage of smaller and cheaper connectors and cable, but needs a much higher bandwidth than parallel. Nevertheless at high speeds also parallel communication may be timing sensitive if there are delay differences between the different lines, so that all signals may not arrive simultaneously.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  USB=Universal Serial Bus.  "Serial" just means that the info comes across the bus one bit at a time, as opposed to parallel schemes where nibbles, bytes, or words come through.  When serial busses were slow, there was more advantage to parallel ports.  These days its hard to buy a computer with a parallel port

Comment: Yeah, know that :D. But how does it differ from the serial communication, used in computers..

Comment: The protocol has "hooks" built into APIs that clue in applications about what sort of information is coming in over the bus.  It's a "standard" so hardware and software developers can assume certain things that make their lives easier.  Hardware-wise, its different from uart in that a) its a bidirectional bus, which means that you don't need one send line and one receive line, and b) the bus is differential.  Of course, this is really overly simplistic- the standard is huge and complicated.  I'll send you to Jan Axelson's USB page at http://www.lvr.com/usb.htm  if you really want detail

Comment: @Anubis it is similar that both are serial (USB 2.0 has one data line; RS-232 has one in each direction), as opposed to parallel, e.g. Parallel ATA which transfers 16 bits in the same instant. It is entirely different in other aspects (you can't simply plug one into the other).

Comment: @exscape: USB has one differential pair for data, not just a single wire.

Comment: @Ben Yes, but it has one "data line", at least as I would define "data line". Two wires, one "line" :)

Answer (score 7):

How do you define "method"? Do you mean protocol? Interface? All of the above?

USB stands for Universal Serial Bus. The [canonical definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) of USB is:

> Universal Serial Bus (USB) is an industry standard developed in the mid-1990s that defines the cables, connectors and communications protocols used in a bus for connection, communication and power supply between computers and electronic devices.

There are numerous device classes associated with USB, like mass storage, HID, audio, all of which have somewhat different protocols and software requirements.

I would argue that USB encompasses *many* methods of serial communication, and is too broad a term to be referred to as a singular method 'per se'.